# How to create a dictionary from data set in python, then create a loop to check each line in data against dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science

I have a large amount of sport data that I am analyzing. I am trying to find the last location of the team (the time zone).

I have created a dictionary from the data which uses 'date' as the input (date of game) and timezone.

What I am trying to do is create the dictionary, then run code to check each line in data and find the previous game date (more specifically, the time zone at the previous date).

This is my code so far

```
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input_folder = '2018files'  # path of folder containing the multiple text files

# create a list with file names 
data_files = [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(input_folder)]

# open csv file for writing
csv = open('myoutput2.csv', 'w')  
def write_to_csv(line):
    print(line)
    csv.write(line)


for file in data_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:  # use context manager to open files
        for line in f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            i=0

            while i < len(lines):
                temp_array = lines[i].rstrip().split(",")
                if temp_array[0] == "id":
                    j=0  
                    game_id = temp_array[1]
                    awayteam = lines[i+2].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    hometeam = lines[i+3].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    date = lines[i+5].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    winning_team=0
                    timezone=0
                    site=0


  #find timezone

                    for z in range(i+4,i+5,1): #only check for site id's
                         temp_array4 = lines[z].rstrip().split(",") #create new array for site id's
                         site = temp_array4[2]
                         site_first_3_letters=site[:3]

                         if str(site_first_3_letters)== "ALB" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="ATL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="BAL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="BOS" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="BUF" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="CAN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="CIN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="CLE" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="CLL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="COL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="COV" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="DAY" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="DET" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="DOV" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="FOR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="FTB" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="GEA" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="GLO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="GRA" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="HAR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="HRT" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="IND" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="IRO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="JER" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="LBV" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="LOU" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="LUD" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MAS" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MIA" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MID" or  str(site_first_3_letters)=="MON" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="NYC" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="PHI" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="PIT" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="PRO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="RIC" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="ROC" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SAI" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SJU" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SPR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="STP" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SYR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="THR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="TOL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="TOR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WAR" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WAT" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WAV" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WEE" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WIL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WNY" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WOR":
                            timezone="GMT-4"

                         elif str(site_first_3_letters)=="ARL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="CHI" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="HOU" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="KAN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="KEO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MIL" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MIN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="MNT" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="RCK" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="STL":
                           timezone="GMT-5"

                         elif str(site_first_3_letters)=="DEN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="PHO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WHE":
                           timezone="GMT-6"

                         elif str(site_first_3_letters)== "ANA" or str(site_first_3_letters)== "LAS" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="LOS" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="OAK" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SAN" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SEA" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="SFA" or str(site_first_3_letters)== "SFO" or str(site_first_3_letters)=="WAS":
                           timezone="GMT-7"


 # First I need to create a dictionary with date and time zone details for all games ANA play

                    schedule_ANA=dict()
                    #ANA is the team I'm interested in
                    if str(hometeam) == "ANA" or str(awayteam) == "ANA":
                        schedule_ANA[date]=str(timezone)
                        # This finds the time zone of the game on that date
                        print (schedule_ANA)


# I want to find the time zone of the the last game
                        # I want to go back 1 day at a time
                        # until the the next game date/time zone occurs

                    current_day_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d')
                    previous_day_object = current_day_object
                    while True: 
                        # move one day back
                        previous_day_object = previous_day_object - timedelta(days = 1)



                        # check if you have a game on that day
                    if previous_day_object.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') in schedule:
                        print("Date of Previous Game",previous_day_object)

                        break


                        #eg. if a game is on 28 June 2018 at GMT-7,  no game on 29 or 30 June
                        # then another game at 1 July 2018 at GMT -4, I want to return GMT -7
                        # when 1 July 2018 is the key



                    #Write to the csv     
                    output_for_csv2=(game_id,date,hometeam,
                                     awayteam,str(site),
                                     str(timezone))


                    csv.write(','.join(output_for_csv2) + '\n')                     
                    i=i+1

                else:

                    i=i+1

                    j=0
                    count_of_plate_appearances=0



csv.close()
```

I am getting this error, even though there are dates before 2018/04/03.

```
{'2018/04/03': 'GMT-7'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/2019sem2/egh400/Code/rev41_test.py", line 73, in <module>
    previous_day_object = previous_day_object - timedelta(days = 1)
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

I think the issue is that I am potentially creating the dictionary as the lines of data are being read, so there is no previous date to compare it to.

Any recommendations on how to fix it?

.
.
.
.

Also, here is some data incase it's useful.

```
id,ANA201804020
version,2
info,visteam,CLE
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/03
id,ANA201804030
version,2
info,visteam,CLE
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/02
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:08PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
play,3,1,river003,32,*B*BCS11*B>X,8/F
data,er,parkb001,0
data,er,woodb004,0
id,ANA201804040
version,2
info,visteam,CLE
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/04
info,number,0
info,starttime,1:08PM
info,daynight,day
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,dimum901
data,er,bedrc001,0
data,er,middk001,0
data,er,woodb004,0
data,er,parkb001,0
data,er,bardl001,0
data,er,ramin002,0
id,ANA201804060
version,2
info,visteam,OAK
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/06
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:07PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,knigb901
start,ramij002,"J.C. Ramirez",1,0,1
play,1,0,joycm001,32,CBBFBFB,W
data,er,ramin002,1
id,ANA201804080
version,2
info,visteam,OAK
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/08
info,number,0
info,starttime,1:08PM
info,daynight,day
data,er,woodb004,0
data,er,penaf002,1
id,ANA201804170
version,2
info,visteam,BOS
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/17
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:09PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,carav901
info,ump1b,bakej902
data,er,bedrc001,1
data,er,johnj010,0
id,ANA201804180
version,2
info,visteam,BOS
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/18
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:08PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,bakej902
data,er,woodb004,1
data,er,bedrc001,0
data,er,middk001,2
id,ANA201804190
version,2
info,visteam,BOS
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/19
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:08PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,laynj901
data,er,bardl001,0
id,ANA201804200
version,2
info,visteam,SFN
info,hometeam,ANA
info,site,ANA01
info,date,2018/04/20
info,number,0
info,starttime,7:08PM
info,daynight,night
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,rippm901
info,ump1b,westj901
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the previous date. Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = '2018/04/03'
previous_day_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d')
while True:
    previous_day_object = previous_day_object - timedelta(days = 1)
```

You see that your loop never ends, or more precisely: ends with an error. You can remove one day, and one day, and ..., but when the date is finally the 1st of January of year 1 (0001-01-01), you can't remove that day anymore:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date.min
>>> d.isoformat()
'0001-01-01'
>>> d - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
OverflowError: date value out of range
```